# Compare Values between same key from map in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I want to compare a different values between same key :

```
map("Robert" , "2010/01/02" , "John" , "2011/02/02" , "Robert" , "2011/02/20")
```

I am trying to compare :
Values between Key Robert : 2010/01/02 & 2011/02/20

Can someone suggest me how can I achieve using reducebykey

Answer (score 0):

You cannot assign multiple values to a single key using a `Map`.

You have to use a mutable `Map[K, Set[V]]` and mix in the MultiMap trait then using the `addBinding` method.

See http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/?_ga=1.225433690.1332072044.1457439940#scala.collection.mutable.MultiMap

If you do that you have the values right at your hand.

Comment: I am able to assign the value , please find the below answer : val docsss = rows.map(r => (r(2),r(1)) docsss.foreach(println)

(11,3 April 2010) 11 is key value = "3 April 2010" (11,14 May 2011) 11 is key value = "14 May 2011"

The problem is when I take this to reducebykey its allowing only value as int, but I am trying to take a string as value. for eg : ("3 April 2010" , "14 May 2011")

Answer (score 0):

I am able to assign the value , please find the below answer :
val docsss = rows.map(r => (r(2),r(1))
docsss.foreach(println)

(11,3 April 2010) 11 is key value = "3 April 2010"
(11,14 May 2011)  11 is key value = "14 May 2011"

The problem is when I take this to reducebykey its allowing only value as int, but I am trying to take a string as value. 
for eg : ("3 April 2010" , "14 May 2011")

Answer (score 0):

Clearly keys being `String`s is not a problem, as you can see from `PairRddFunctions` signature:

```
 class PairRDDFunctions[K, V](self: RDD[(K, V)])(implicit kt: ClassTag[K], vt: ClassTag[V], ord: Ordering[K] = null)
```

keys can be any type.

I even created simple test to check this:

```
val r = sc.parallelize(Seq("Robert" -> "2010/01/02" , "John" -> "2011/02/02" , "Robert" -> "2011/02/20"))
r.reduceByKey(_ + " " +_).foreach(println)
```

Results:

```
(John,2011/02/02)
(Robert,2010/01/02 2011/02/20)
```

---

Please provide some further details about your code, namely:

1. types of your `RDD`s
2. more complete code snippet of what is not working
3. error message that you have
4. elaborate on what you mean by "compare different values". Maybe something like `groupByKey` will be better fit here

---

**Updated example:**

```
import java.time.LocalDate
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter

def parseDate(d:String) =
  LocalDate.parse(d,
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy/MM/dd"))

// ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(d1, d2)


val r = sc.parallelize(Seq("Robert" -> "2010/01/02" , "John" -> "2011/02/02" , "Robert" -> "2011/02/20",
  "Robert" -> "2011/02/20"))

implicit def localDateOrdering = Ordering.by[LocalDate, Long](_.toEpochDay)

r.groupByKey.flatMap {
  case (key, vals) =>
    val valsArr = vals.toArray
    valsArr.map(parseDate) match {
      case x if x.length >= 3 && ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(x.min, x.max) > 10 =>
        valsArr.map(key -> _)
      case _ => Nil
    }
}.foreach(println)
```

Result is:

```
(Robert,2010/01/02)
(Robert,2011/02/20)
(Robert,2011/02/20)
```

I'm using `groupByKey` to group records with same key into `iterator`, then in `flatMap` iterator is buffered in `Array`, validated according to the rule (length > 3 and largest difference in days is > 10) and then, if current key complies to the rules, all records with that key are restored to the original state.

Even if I didn't completely understand your requirements I hope that you can modify that example in accordance to your needs.

Comment: my business logic is : I have 3 records in a file 1) Key is Transaction id and value is transaction date  Record 1 ( Key : T1 Value : 2015/02/02 ) Record 2 (Key : T2 Value : 2015/03/02 ) Record3 (Key : T1 Value : 2015/02/15) when i consider the record Key T1, there is 2 dates accociate with it. I want to compare the values ( 2015/02/02 , 2015/02/15) .

Comment: @jk7, do you have only three records in the file? Are you using spark to parse this file? How many files do you have? What about other questions I asked?

Comment: I am using Spark to parse the file. I am pulling the data from avro table using dataframe and converting in to RDD . I just gave 3 record as an example. The file will have huge record.

Comment: @jk7, ok, so as you see from my tiny example, `reduceByKey` should work. What error are you getting? Or what else doesn't work?

Comment: Reduce key works only when value is Int, but in my case i am trying to use value as string, for eg  Key1   Value : "2015/01/01" , "2015/02/02" can we able to use string as value in reducebykey?

Comment: @jk7, it doesn't matter what type are your keys and values, `reduceByKey` accepts any. Perhaps the problem is in the function that you are supplying to `reduceByKey`? Sorry, but I can't guess your problem without any help from your side.

Comment: For eg : The map has key T1 and it has value "2015/02/02" , 2015/02/15 " , "2015/03/01" , "2015/03/20" I am trying to find the rolling difference . the expected answer is if the difference between the dates is less then 10 days between each days,then i will consider the record for further process.

Comment: @jk7, ok, it makes sense now. What result type do you expect? Is it the original dataset with some added flag if difference from previous date for the same key was > 10d  (like `RDD[(String, String, Boolean)]`), or just filtered rdd of the keys where there were at least any values with difference > 10 (`RDD[String]`) , or...?

Comment: My aim is if any key satisfy atleast 3 dates with in the list of values(dates) in 10 days range, then i want to qualify the record in to output file.

Comment: Hi AIvean, thanks for the details. But my logic is to get the difference between all values lets say ("Robert" -> "2010/01/02" , "John" -> "2011/02/02" , "Robert" -> "2011/02/20",
  "Robert" -> "2011/02/20"))
Key Robert has 3 value(dates) : (Robert,2010/01/02:   2011/02/20:   2011/02/18) , I want to do a sort on this dates and find difference between each date and if the difference is less then 10 days then I want to increment a count, for ee 2011/02/20 & 2011/02/18 is less then 10 days , so I want to increase a count. The example what you state it gives on min and max.

Comment: Hi Aivean, please let me know your thoughts